# how can i determine which button was clicked in angular material dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MD_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Dialog Overview
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example.html'
})
export class DialogOverviewExample {

  animal: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

  openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MD_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Let's say i have the code as above. And the result shown below:

[image]

Based on this picture, how can i determine if the user clicked OK or No thanks. I want to create a function for each event. tried dialogRefAfterClose but it runs no matter what button i click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your dialog html, dialog-overview-example-dialog.html, You can just add (click) event in your both button.

```
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="clickOK()" tabindex="2">Ok</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="clickNo()" tabindex="-1">No Thanks</button>
</div>
```

and you can close the dialog programmaticly:

```
clickNo() {
    console.log('No button clicked');
    this.dialogRef.close();
}
clickOk() {
    console.log('Ok button clicked');
    this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

Comment: yeah, Thats exactly the way to go

Answer (score 2):

Hi I noticed that you are using the exact same example from angular.material. 
The option you asked for need to be handled by Yourself according to your purpose. As seen in the example there.
[my example](https://plnkr.co/edit/GkveROw9fIQuHraVL6Rg)

In here the **onNoClick()** and the **onOkClick()** does the Job
Add the functions in compontent ts  and bind it in the component html

**Dialog Component TS**

```
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    alert("You clicked no.")
    this.dialogRef.close();

  }
  onOkClick():void{

    alert("You clicked Ok");
  }
}
```

**Dialog Component HTML**

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput tabindex="1" [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onOkClick()" [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" tabindex="2">Ok</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()" tabindex="-1">No Thanks</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with single `function`, no need to add functions for more buttons

Like this :

```
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="clickBtn(true)" tabindex="2">Ok</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="clickBtn(false)" tabindex="-1">No Thanks</button>
</div>

clickBtn(status) {
    if(status)
        console.log('Ok button clicked');
    else 
        console.log('No button clicked');    
    this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

Comment: Dude.. We all know all these are same. But there is a coding standard that says to write one function to do one matter. write second function to handle second job. Its more readable. So plz don't follow this practice

Comment: It matter's upon the functions , for single line of code it's not preferaable to make function for each, you can also make calls from single function, there is standard for this , until your code is readable.

Comment: Do you really think if the PO asked the question, He wouldnt want to do business logic over there and write a one liner?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button  mat-button  (click)="onNoClick()"  [mat-dialog-close]="data.SelectedBtn">No Thanks</button>
  <button  mat-button  (click)="onOkClick()"  [mat-dialog-close]="data.SelectedBtn" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
 templateUrl: './dialog.html',
})
export class DialogComponent {

 constructor(
public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) { }

 onNoClick(): void {
this.data.SelectedBtn = false;
this.dialogRef.close(this.data.SelectedBtn);
}

onOkClick(): void {
  this.data.SelectedBtn = true;
  this.dialogRef.close(this.data.SelectedBtn);
}


}
```